# How do I call the operands in a modulo operation?

Tags: mathematics

In an equation `7 - 3 = 4`, the `7` is called **minuend** and the `3` is called **subtrahend**.

Then what are the appropriate terms for the `7`, `3`, `1` in `7 ≡ 1 (mod 3)`?

Comment: *Minuend* and *subtrahend* are very old-fashioned terms. I never had to learn them, even 50 years ago. I would just call them *arguments*. You might get a more informed opinion at [Mathematics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mick I don't consider them old-fashioned; they are instead *domain-specific*.  I learned them at some point in my mathematical education.  There's not a lot of call for them outside of a math context, so most people probably forget about them about 30 seconds after learning them.

Comment: @Hellion: I'm no mathematician, but I'd be pretty certain the number of people writing in English about such things has increased over the past half-century. During which period the prevalence of both these terms has apparently [***gone down by about 75%,***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minuend%2Csubtrahend&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cminuend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubtrahend%3B%2Cc0) so I think what Mick says is right - they're going out of fashion.

Comment: @Hellion I suppose it depends on what education system you went through. In the UK state system, *numerator*, *denominator*, *product* and *divisor* was about as far as it went. I did go on to study maths at degree level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, **7** is the

> dividend

and **3** is the

> divisor

[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: To take things one step further, the modulo operation can be defined in terms of integer division.  In that case, 3 is the divisor, 7 is the dividend, 2 is the quotient, and 1 is the remainder.  The statement "7 is congruent to 1, modulo 3" means that the divisors 7 and 1 have the same remainder (1, obviously) when the divisor is 3.